# creating a method that can return multiple objects in Java

Tags: java, object, methods

In java i would like to create a method that can return multiple objects like a couple of int values,  strings, float , double etc. what is the way to do this?

Comment: Define a class and return an instance of it.

Comment: Start learning about arrays and collections.

Comment: Is there some clear format(e.g int,int,string,double) ?

Comment: integers, floats and doubles aren't objects!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a class that encapsulates all you desired return types.

Like the following:

```
public class MyReturnValues {
    private int integer1;
    private int integer2;
    private String myString;
    //etc

    public MyReturnValues() {
    }

    public MyReturnValues(int integer1, int integer2, String myString) {
        this.integer1 = integer1;
        this.integer2 = integer2;
        this.myString = myString;
    }

    public int getInteger1() {
        return integer1;
    }

    public void setInteger1(int integer1) {
        this.integer1 = integer1;
    }

    public int getInteger2() {
        return integer2;
    }

    public void setInteger2(int integer2) {
        this.integer2 = integer2;
    }

    public String getMyString() {
        return myString;
    }

    public void setMyString(String myString) {
        this.myString = myString;
    }
}
```

And then you set this as your return value for your method:

```
public MyReturnValues myMethod() {
//your code that creates the MyReturnValue using constructor or setter methods
}
```

To access the values, just call the get method on the class:

```
int integer1 = myMethod().getInteger1();
//etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array as return type

```
public int[] returnIntValues(){
    int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
    return arr;
}
```